# Backup SQL Server database using SaveFileDialog vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Here is some VB.NET code for backing up our SQL Server 2014 database.  When I run the code, the error message shown is "Incorrect syntax error".

```
Dim sqlcon As New SqlConnection With {.ConnectionString = "Server=USMAN; Database=test; Persist Security Info=True; User ID=sa; Password=123"}
Private Sub btnBackUp_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBackUp.Click
    SaveFileDialog1.FileName = DateAndTime.DateString + " - test"
    SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "SQL Server database backup files|*.bak"
    SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    Dim cmdbak As New SqlCommand("backup database test to disk '" & SaveFileDialog1.FileName & "'", sqlcon)
    sqlcon.Open()
    cmdbak.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MessageBox.Show("Backup has been successfully.")
    sqlcon.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: `...to disk = 'diskname'`

Comment: now error "Cannot open backup device 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup'. Operating system error 5(Access is denied.).
BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally"

Comment: You don't have access rights to Save File in C Drive Path.  Save backup in other Drive Like D:, E: etc.

Comment: Dear hardikpatel, still same error

Comment: Backup operates on the server's local drive even if you are using a remote station.

Comment: Are you trying to backup a local system or a remote database? The connectionstring suggests a remote one... which means it's going to attempt to backup to THAT file system NOT your local drive. The server doesn't see your local drive. It only sees its own system. That's why it's failing. You need to give it a path that it knows and recognizes.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to backup a local system. I hope, this code is correct but not run perfectly. So, I need your assistance for the problem. You have to see this code, if you feel any error in this code then you help me. Thanks

Comment: Please write some code for that how to take backup from local system or local server. Please send me correct code. Thanks